# Error timespan codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, timespan

I'm trying to calcute the time between now and a given time. But when I use timespan I get this error:

Fatal error: Call to undefined function timespan() in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/VERSIE0.1/application/views/welcome_message.php on line 54
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: ErrorMessage: Call to undefined function timespan()Filename: views/welcome_message.phpLine Number: 54Backtrace:

```
<span class="time"><?php


                                 $post_date = $t['story_date'];
                                   $now = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

                                   echo timespan($post_date, $now);

                                   ?> 
</span>
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this

- Load helper ( $this->load->helper('date'))

or You can use  this

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-diff.php

Answer (score 3):

In order to use the `timespan` function you need to load its library, the `helper`.

Make sure you write:

```
$this->load->helper('date');
```

- [Date helper manual](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/date_helper.html)
- [How to use helpers](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/helpers.html)

Answer (score 0):

Right answer is to include the helper on your view file. Just load the helper

```
$this->load->helper('date');
```

in your view, not in controller.